# Build url query string than contain multiple value in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

On a search page with url than act like filter some argument can be set more than one time.

So in a twig template I'm trying to build an url like that:

```
app?param1=2&toto[]=3&toto[]=10&toto[]=20
```

How do you manage to do that in twig?

I'm already merging the request query with entity attribute (in a loop)

```
path('search', app.request.query.all | merge({state: state.id}))
```

Comment: `{{ path('search', { 'param1': 1, 'param2': ['a','b']}) }}`

Gives me app?param1=1&param2%5B0%5D=a&course%5B1%5D=b. Is this functionally equivalent to what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this in you're view, build it in your controller and pass it down to the view.

Views should be logic-less IMO.

Comment: I end up using a pipe to separate the values of a query string and move all the split/merge logic in the controller.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, it's possible to do this with Twig, but they make it hard on purpose.